# How do I pass a parameter from model to layout in Zend 2?

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

What i wan to achieve is to extract some data from db in my model and send it to layout, where is my main menu is located. I want to change that menu after what value i got in that parameter from model. 
This is the class module content:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

       // $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
        //$x = new UserController();
        // $var =  $x->getUserSession();
        // $viewModel->someVar = $var;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {

        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Application\Model\UsersTable' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table = new Model\UsersTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Some said, I can used a Helper, other said that i have to modify the onBootstrap function. It is really messed up all of my head with this. Can you provide me an example how do i make this working? thx

Comment: Please describe more specifically about what you want to attach to your navigation. I'm only guessing that you don't want any of the examples you're mentioned (helper or inject in onBootstrap, last one should be lightweight so it's not well seen to attach there anything from db). I bet that You want extend default Navigation class :) but as I said You should describe your case more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $data = $controller->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\UsersTable')->functionToGetData();
        $controller->layout()->data= $data;
    }, 100); 
}
```

Then $data parameter is available to your layout. Just to be clear when you say layout i assume you mean the default layout

Update: I find it difficult to express my way of understanding so in order to avoid confusion i will quote some theories from the documentation and other sources that helped me understand the above. You should read the references i provide at the end and you will get the idea.

The onBootstrap() method is called for every module implementing this feature, on every page request, and should only be used for performing lightweight tasks such as registering event listeners.

An EventManager is really only interesting if it triggers some events.

Basic triggering takes three arguments: - The event name, which is usually the current function/method name; - The target, which is usually the current object instance; - The arguments, which are usually the arguments provided to the current function/method

In turn, triggering events is only interesting if something is listening for the event.

Listeners attach to the EventManager, specifying a named event and the callback to notify. The callback receives an Event object, which has accessors for retrieving the event name, target, and parameters. Let’s add a listener, and trigger the event.

A shared event manager is a manage which is unique across the application, and that is injected into each event manager

So in other words the onBootstrap method will attach the event using the sharedEvents and then trigger them. For better understanding of this consepts please have a look on the following references.

[The MvcEvent](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html)

[Module Manager Listeners](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html)

[The EventManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html)

[Understanding the Zend Framework 2 event manager](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/12/understanding-the-zend-framework-2-event-manager/)

Comment: it works, but i absoluty no idea what happens in that onBootstrap function, can u explain me ? thx

Comment: Will explain on monday :)

Comment: ok, srry for my late response, but please don't forget on monday :)

Comment: If i do just post here. :)

Comment: one more question, is this possible to call a function from a controller not a  model ?

Comment: No. But...use plugins. Quite easy to create one and the methods in plugins can be accesed by any controller or the module.php

Comment: and that plugin can be access in my onBootstrap function ?

Comment: Yes. You will use the  $controller object to create an object of the plugin class and access your method

Comment: Yes but plugins should be a new question

Comment: i will be glad receiving your answer also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136920/how-do-i-set-up-a-new-layout-to-a-new-module-in-zend-2. THX